# Foreach in sql with static data

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have 3 tables:

Countries:

```
Code, Name
```

Vacances:

```
id(autoincrement),CountryCode, NameOfCountry, numberOfdays
```

How to foreach country insert Row:

```
countryCode,'Welcome in " + nameofCountry +"!",12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
    insert Vacances(CountryCode, NameOfCountry, numberOfdays)
    select distinct  [Code],'Welcome to ' + [Name] +'!',12
    from Countries
```

No need for loops, databases are optimized for SET based operations, take advantage of that

Answer (score 3):

No need for a loop or "foreach"...

```
INSERT Vacances (CountryCode, NameOfCountry, numberOfdays)
SELECT countryCode, 'Welcome in ' + Name + '!', 12
FROM Countries
```

Comment: Sorry, added some text to your instead of mine  :-) I removed it..it was the sentence about SET based